# How to parse PubKeyHash hash into a Plutus Smart Contract for on Chain Validation

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

I am trying to use a PubKeyHash as a variable in my on-Chain code, something like this:

```
pkh :: PubKeyHash
pkh = "dca6035712f164db2f99c71404d392115d2bdde366fbbe359ae01f1d"
```

But this does not work, just give me a strange error when compiling  I tried to add the In-linable but that did not work either. I tried with some BuildIn constructors as well and that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use PubKeyHash by using parameterized smartcontract code like I have showed in another question [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6157/4596)

Comment: It seems so strange to me that parametrizing works but not direcly :s